# function is undefined when i'm calling it inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

That's one of the weirdest thing I have ever encountered in JavaScript maybe some of you know the reason it behaves the way it does.

If you will run this code you will get undefined

```js
var fn = function(div,speed){

}

(function(){console.log(fn)}())
```

BUT if we add a variable

```js
var fn = function(div,speed){

}
var weird = true;
(function(){console.log(fn)}())
```

Now it will return the function

I don't understand what on earth is going on?

It can also work like that

```js
var fn = function(div,speed){
}

!function(){console.log(fn)}()
```

Comment: Missing semicolon. ASI strikes again

Comment: ohh you right now i see the problem the syntax parser will see that like that var fn = function(div,speed){} (function(){console.log(fn)})

Comment: I suggest getting a linter with an autofix option (ESLint has it), enabling the rule that mandates semicolons and making the linter automatically insert any semicolons it needs. Saves you the hassle. A linter is useful anyway to spot errors like this one. It can also autofix other style related problems.